Is there any way to make familiars useful at higher (10+) levels of play?
Here's my problem.
I'm playing an Arcanist, currently level 12, Mythic 1 (fresh after level-up), so called god-wizard build (plenty of CC and pre-combat buffs for fights and swiss-army-knife for everything outside combat).
I have a familiar, Faerie Dragon (taken with Improved Familiar feat) that was a switch from my initial Thrush (which I gave to my cohort when I was taking Improved Familiar Feat).
Before Improved Familiar my Thrush was there just for occassional skill assists (especially diplomacy since I'm party's face), after Improved Familiar my Faerie Dragon was the best scout any party could ask for.
Then come level 10+. Planar Binding and my new best scout Zebub comes into fray. Does everything that Faerie Dragon can but better. I also have Prying Eyes for when I need to scan large area quickly. My familiar became completely redundant and there's nothing else on the Improved Familiar creatures list that can do what I don't have already covered. Familiar on my cohort (witch) is even worse, if it wasn't also the witch's spellbook it might as well not exist.
Now, I know there are archetypes, but apart from Figment, that I'm considering now (effectively a Paragon Surge spell every morning, better than a non-familiar I have now) there's nothing even remotely useful there. Valet could be acceptable in campaigns with tight time constraints (half the crafting time) but we closer to open world than story driven campaign so that doesn't apply to us.
What I expect from familiar? One of the:

Utility. Some spells and SLA's that could lessen the burden on, my already strained, spell slots (Arcanist has fewest spell slots of all 9/9 spellcasting classes).
Statblock that allows it to do things on it's own. Let's say send it as an advisor to local king would require familiar to have similar Diplomacy to me, alongside some usefull SLA's for social encounters.

Examples of what I would consider a usefull familiar (this wouldn't be RAW but just showing my expectations):

Familiar leveling like a class, accumulating feats and possibly new SLA's,

...OR...

Improved Familiar list that scales to like 10 HD or 10 CR at level 20 with full access to entire bestiary, not just a couple of selected creatures. On my current level Zebub would make a perfect familiar but in a couple levels this will also be too weak to consider.

[DISCLAIMER: We're talking RAW, well optimized play although not cheesy play.]
If there's a good familiar-centered content in 3pp books I'd love to get answers based on those. Easier to sell 3pp to GM than accept defeat and throw familiar class feature right into trash can.

While I do not think the question is broad enough to vote to close I feel like being given more specifics on what kind of enemies the campaign entails as well as your archetype could help narrow down the answer you get. For example Emissary’s Emboldening feat is particularly useful in a campaign where fear effects are common but may prove to be useless otherwise.  Then there are archetype exclusive spells. For example if you have school savant archetype then you could use school familiar feat.

Edited and added a lot to the question. Hope there's enough details now.

With your additions, it sounds like you want your familiar to be more like a summoner's eidolon or an animal companion. Is that a fair assessment?

I just want it to be useful. And things that can be done better with something else, without any tradeoffs or downsides within the same level options are not useful.

Ok, I'll be interested to see if others have any better suggestions.

Though for the specific example of planar binding, it does have the spell slot cost which was one of your listed concerns. Plus a dimensional anchor to keep it from just teleporting out. Plus the other risks that come with that spell and using a compelled creature to do your bidding.

What spell slot cost? Planar Binding lasts for days, months with contract. You bind creature in downtime and have it de facto permanently.

Ah I see, Honestly, I've never used planar binding because my dm's homebrew doesn't have summoning. With that application of the spell, open ended contracts to maximize time, it seems like a super powerful spell which would eclipse plenty of class features. And it looks like familiar may be one of them. Again, interested to see if any one else has a solution for you.

Protector Familiar
My preferred use for a familiar at high level is the Protector archetype familiar. An improved familiar can not take it because they never get Speak with Animals of It's Kind, but at it improves your AC, at level 5 it increases your effective HP by 50% and at level 11 it increases your effective HP by 100% while also giving you an emergency "Stay alive" with In Harm's Way. With the damage numbers that can come out in high level play these abilities have saved my character from death a couple times.
Buff Monkey
Another effective use for a familiar at high level is getting one capable of using wands and scrolls. For the cost of a little gold it halves the time required to get your buffs up in an emergency.
I have never been able to find a solid consensus on familiars being capable of activating wands and scrolls, but from our interpretation of the rules, my DM has ruled that a familiar with hands, the ability to speak (or a ring of eloquence), and a master with enough ranks in UMD can use one.
Also there is no reason these two can't be combined effectively since your protector familiar should never be far from you.

Protector seems amazing for Magus or Sorcerer that like to get involved. For stay-in-the-back god-wizard support caster it doesn't do anything because if I'm ever dropped below 50% hp this means entire team is dead already.
As for wands, I barely ever use them. I either buff myself or use one of my several planar bound creatures to buff me with things I don't have access to. Wands are getting obsolete roughly at the same time familiars are.

You're reaching the part of the game where permanently-invisible and teleporting monsters start to appear.  There is no "back row", there is "oh thank the gods we can see that one" and "WHERE DID THAT COME FROM".

As an alternate to the buff monkey concept, any familiar with hands can have a set of poisoner's gloves with a potion loaded in them, which they can deliver to their master while hidden in their clothes without using the master's action.  An excellent place to keep an emergency potion.

gatherer818, "THAT DID COME FROM" (my planar bound Erinyes with constant True Seeing points finger at the square enemy is in) or from "I'm sorry my immediate action counterspell says you don't get to teleport behind me". And this part of the game requires stripping me of several buffs before I can be harmed anyway. Which is why I'm looking for some unique use for familiar. Because obviously in combat it can't hold a candle to Planar Binding.

Probably not worth it's own answer, but why not just planar bind a Efreet and wish your familiar was whatever you want it to be?
But really, I'd be interested to hear about your buff setup and menagerie of bindings. Seems very powerful, but maybe this isn't the place for that discussion.

If someone moves this comment section to chat I'll be more than happy to answer. Maybe this will give you some insight into what I'm looking for. Btw. I already have Efreeti, but at our table we use unpaid Wishes only to replicate other spells. Good for free Permanencies and some occasional niche-spell-list buffs but that's about it.
